# Why can't I import config into my Ember helper without typing the name?

Tags: ember-cli

I have a helper **helpers/asset.js** that needs to import the config.

This works:

```
import ENV from 'sixtysevenjourney/config/environment';
```

This doesn't

```
import ENV from '../../config/environment';
```

In the latter case it just says it can't import **config/environment** from **helpers/assets**, why can't I do a relative import?

Answer (score 0):

Your import will work if you do this:

```
import ENV from '../config/environment';
```

Notice that your code is under `app/`, but when you import using

```
import ENV from 'sixtysevenjourney/config/environment';
```

You don't put the **app** part

```
import ENV from 'sixtysevenjourney/**app**/config/environment';
```

I don't know how things work internally for this to work. Hope that helps